# I have two keystore files, but I forgot which one I used to sign the APK

Tags: android, keystore

I need to update my app on Play store, but I forgot that which Keystore I used to sign the APK. is there any way to identify this?

Comment: if you don't remember the keystore file then there is no other way you can update the app.

Comment: i have 2 file but i don't know any one is true

Comment: If you have sure the Keystore from the tow you have, Then just try with both one by one.

Answer (score 1):

try to use one keystore and build apk and upload to playstore alpha/internal test if selected keystore is incorrect play store throw exception

Answer (score 1):

To know the keystore you used for siging the APK, You need to identify SHA1 key of keystore. Unzip the APK and open "META-INF" folder in terminal. Run the following command: -

```
keytool -printcert -file CERT.RSA
```

This will print the SHA1 key. Just verify this key with your both keystores. To know the SHA1 of the keystore use following command in terminal: -

```
keytool -exportcert -alias aliname -keystore youkeystore.jks | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: first command worked perfect. But second one didn't. Instead I tried `keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore file path> -alias <alias name>`. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with both one by one increasing version, Like first create sign APK with first one upload it on play store console if google throw exception then increase version code and try with second one and upload again on play store.
As if you are saying Keystore from you have then it will be match and your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Do I need to use the same alias with password ?or create new one?

Comment: You need to use the same alias and password, If you just know the password then you can select the alias directly.